# How to keep html table on same line without specifying a width?

Tags: css, width, overflow, inline, html-table

I can't seem to keep my (dynamic width) table on the same line as a previous element and have it extend to it's parent container without exceeding it and overflowing. I don't want a horizontal scrollbar as the table should just break the lines and/or words up to make it more narrow.
However, it's not doing that.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johntrepreneur/gDLdE/)

In the fiddle, the table overflows and extends beyond it's parent container's width. The parent container is using `white-space: nowrap` to keep it on the same line as the content next to it.

Why is it not sizing it's width correctly?
If I set a fixed width on the table, it works and sizes the width correctly, but I need the width of the table to be dynamic. Only the outermost containing div is fixed.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to use % for width instead of set pixels.  Your image width + the table width is exceeding the parent element's total width.

Comment: @Siva - Thanks but I tried that. Problem with that is the % is that of the first parent with an explixitly defined width which is the overall div in my example. I tried setting it to like 37% which worked when there were no vertical scrollbars, but failed when the vertical srollbars appeared as the scrollbar doesn't affect the width of that outermost div where the width is explicitly defined.

Answer (score 1):

If you add

```
.listInfoTbl {
[...]
    max-width: 142px;
[...]
}
```

then you'll see everything is working. But you may wonder why is that?

The answer is that you set a certain width for your div.listPropertyDiv therefore it won't grow beyond this and additionally there's some padding to take into the formula:

```
innerWidth(.listPropertyDiv) = innerWidth(#left) - border(.listPropertyDiv) - padding(.listPropertyDiv) - margin(.listPropertyDiv)
innerWidth(.listPropertyDiv) = 397px
Therefore: 
width(table.listInfoTbl) <= innerWidth(.listPropertyDiv) - width(img.listImage)
width(table.listInfoTbl) <= 142px
```

You should overthink having a fixed width on #left, if your thinking about dynamically changing the content's width because if the parent doesn't shrink it's children can't.

[A fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gDLdE/4/)
But maybe this [is what you're looking for](http://jsfiddle.net/gDLdE/5/) a solution with max-width and percentage so objects can shrink accordingly.